# convert specific objects to buttons after importing .eps file from illustrator to InDesign

Tags: adobe-indesign

This is my first time working with InDesign and after completeing a basic tutorial I imported an .ai file as eps to InDesign. I want to create an interactive pdf, to make the text boxes appear and disappear with a single click, but I cannot find an answer anywhere on how to do this and if it is even possible. Can anyone provide an answer and/or a tutorial ?

Comment: Try to focus on the core issue next time when you ask a question. The fact that the indesign file is imported from an eps is not relevant.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "Buttons and Forms" Panel for this:
Make show & hide buttons (they can also be over each other and show the other one on click). And set the show/hide actions to the buttons.

<sup>ps. If you are just beginning in Indesign, Interactivity may be too complicated for you.</sup>
[image]